# PolyAnalyst: Is there a way to read in the bookmarks of a PDF file?

Tags: nlp

I have a PDF with bookmarks. I tried to read it into PolyAnalyst but looks like it completely ignores the bookmarks. Is there a way to make PA keep the bookmarks of the file?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no method of extracting pdf bookmark metadata. You can, however, extract bookmark metadata from a Microsoft Word file.